# C++, what does pointer really mean? when virtual involved

Tags: c++, pointers, virtual

For the following code

```
class A 
{
public:
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "a"  << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual ~B()
    {
        std::cout << "b"  << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B* b = new B();
    A* a = b;

    if (a == b)
    {

    }

    delete a;
}
```

Question is , will “a” equals to “b” ? Why and How this happened?
And what a pointer really means? Not just an address and the length of the memory block?

Comment: Yes, the address that `a` points to will be equal to the address that `b` points to, unless multiple inheritance is involved. Then C++ just gets weird...

Comment: The object pointed to by `b` is a `B`, but it is also an `A`.  So a pointer to an `A` object can point to `b`, since `*b` is an `A`

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior. You're deleting a `B` object through the base class `A *` but `A`'s destructor is not `virtual`

Answer (score 3):

> will “a” equals to “b” ?

Yes

> Why and How this happened?

To perform the comparison of the two pointers the compiler will perform a conversion to a common type. In this case, as `A` is a base of `B`, the conversion is to `A*`, yielding code equivalent to:

```
A* __tmp = b;
if ( a == __tmp ) ...
```

> And what a pointer really means? Not just an address and the length of the memory block?

A pointer is a variable the holds the address of an object (no size information stored in the pointer). But the pointer has a type, and the compiler will interpret the memory location that the pointer refers to be an object of that type. That extra information that is stored outside of the pointer is what allows the compiler to perform the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The `a` variable will point at the `A` class portion of the allocated `b` object.  A pointer is just a memory address, nothing more.  What is important is what kind of data the pointer is pointing at in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Let's split the answer in three parts

#### Pointers

A pointer is a variable which holds the memory address of another variable. The type of the pointed variable is important and will be checked by the compiler. One can force the pointer mechanic by using pointers to void (should be avoided in C++, unless you really know what you are doing).

#### Accessing derived class objects using base class pointers

An object, i.e. a variable, of a derived class (`b` in your code) can be referred to using a pointer to its parent type (`A` in your code). This will allow you to access the members of A that are present in `B`. As already stated by Richard J. Ross, using a pointer to the base class will yield the same address as using the derived class pointer (unless multiple inheritance is involved).

#### Virtual functions

Virtual methods allow you to call an overloaded method of the derived object using a base class pointer. This is especially useful for destructors because one can rest assured that **objects will be properly destroyed even when using a base class pointer** (assuming the destructor is well written).

Still, **your code is conceptually wrong**. Because the destructor of `A` is not virtual, the destructor of the `B` part of `b` will not be called, hence there might be memory leaks and similar problems.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I know the program wrong, and deliberately making it this way. but the problem is the address of a and b is not the same,

Answer (score 0):

As David already mentioned, simple comparison of two pointers `a == b` will give you True because the compiler will cast both of them to the common type.
But, if you were to modify this to `(void*)a == (void*)b`, result *may* be false. 
This is because classes A and B have different memory layouts due to B having a virtual function table and A - not.

MSVC compiler puts virtual function pointer on the "top" of the class, before the first data member, but nothing stops other compilers from placing it on the "bottom".

You may also try making class A destructor virtual.

Answer (score 0):

I found some explain on inside c++ object model, this is just like multiple inheritance, the vptr locates at the beginning of the object.
when the base class having no virtual and child class having a virtual, the assign of pointer will be adjusted by the compiler by step over the vptr,

Answer (score -1):

The example is a comparison between two pointers.  As they are pointing to the same location, a will be equal to b.

Comment: no, a and b doesn't pointer to the same address, tested on win32, vc2005

Comment: Oops, I get it now, so a will not be equal to b.

Comment: So are you comparing pointers or are you comparing after dereference the pointers i.e. if (*a==*b)?